# Запретить мобильную адаптацию Select

Tags: html, css

Нужно запретить автоматическое всплывающее окно на телефонах/планшетах, когда нажимаешь на Select, так как необходимо для мобильных развернуть выпадалку в строку.
data-role не работает.

```html
<select size="4" data-role="none">
    <option value="" hidden selected>Выбрать</option>
    <option>Яблоко</option>
    <option>Груша</option>
    <option>Персик</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Что за `data-role`? Это вроде не дефолтный атрибут ... Что в конечном итоге вы планируете получить? В теории можно задать просто селекту атрибут `disabled`, тогда всплывать не будет, но не ясно как вы дальше планируете этим элементом распорядиться...